# How to have prettier format imports on multiple lines

Tags: reactjs, prettier

I want multiline formatting for imports, but prettier collapses into a single line. What option should I use to get the desired behavior

```
-import {
-  BLOCKED_FETCHED,
-  SHORTLISTED_FETCHED,
-} from './../constants/ActionTypes';
+import { BLOCKED_FETCHED, SHORTLISTED_FETCHED } from "./../constants/ActionTypes";
```

Comment: Prettier is not a good choice for a formatter if you want configurability. It's core  premise is that you need not think about style choices, allowing it to apply its opinionated consistency. You'll likely need to write your own plugin for another formatter, like eslint's `--fix` flag, or postprocess with a script, a build tool, or your IDE. On the other hand, you could embrace prettier's ethos and just ignore subjective stylistic things like this.

Comment: Agreed, how do I avoid formatting imports into a single line. There are other aspects which like prettier for

Comment: The Lower the [print-width](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width), the earlier the line (any line) will collapse.

Comment: For the most part Prettier is all or nothing. What you are attempting simply cannot be accomplished. As @AjeetShah mentioned, you can shorten the print width, but this will have other, mostly negative, effects.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Prettier, try Eslint if you want configurability for your style. In this particular case, the `object-curly-newline` option set to `'always'`, paired with the CLI's `--fix` parameter, will accomplish what you desire.

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-curly-newline#always

Comment: The above is not fixing the problem either in a effective fashion